Delta Shower Cartridge Issues Need Help
I replaced my Delta Shower Cartridge and now the water is not as hot as before. The sink in the same bathroom has almost scalding hot water. The cartridge was installed properly with hot on the left side. I also pulled out the white knob and turned it all of the way counter clockwise.
Suggestions appreciated. Thanks
